# Did WW2 airplanes ever jettison their empty external fuel tanks to act as weapons?

Tags: fuel-tanks, bomber, wwii

Jettisoning an external fuel tank over a populated area is prohibited by the FAA as it will *almost certainly* cause **injury and damage to the people in that area**.
But did war airplanes during World War 2 ever use that fact to their *advantage*?

As an example, say a P-51 Mustang dropped its bombs onto a city/town as a part of its mission, and then they realize that their external fuel tanks are empty, and are ready to be jettisoned. Well, couldn't the P-51 just jettison the external fuel tanks over the city/town to cause some *additional damage*?

So, did war airplanes during World War 2 ever actually jettison their empty external fuel tanks over bombing targets to cause additional damage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, and not even empty tanks. It didn’t always work, but it’s happened:

[This is how American pilots used drop tanks as bombs during WWII](https://www.wearethemighty.com/popular/wwii-drop-tank-bombs/).

Fun fact, cellulose drop tanks were developed to save metal during the war! The article references P-47s, but I would not be surprised if P-51s did the same.

Comment: I clearly recall reading about the "Flying Tigers" using the drop tanks of their P-40s in this fashion.  I don't recall whether or not  the account specifically said that they had to go back and fire at the impact area w/ their guns to cause ignition.  And whether the account I read was actually true-- who knows, unfortunately I can't recall the source--

Comment: Btw, regarding the link referenced in this answer -- P-47s did not actually have "cannons", only 50-caliber machine guns.